# Install kotlin on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: android, jenkins, kotlin

i have installed kotlin

```
sudo snap install kotlin
 snap "kotlin" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

but when  I am trying to run it's its giving error

```
 kotlinc: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed java?
Try this:

```
apt install default-jre
```

Comment: i have installed sudo apt install default-jdk

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOMA enviroment variable?